# I'm having trouble accessing GTM script in web crawler projecteb crawler

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I need to access the datalayer for a web crawler project and validate the data in this datalayer, but my code is having a problem when trying to access the GTM script, it jumps to the configured error message.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const {google} = require('googleapis');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  try {
    // Código para extrair o datalayer aqui
    async function getGtmDataLayer(page) {
      // Insira aqui o ID do seu container do GTM
      const gtmContainerId = 'GTM-xxxxxxx';
    
       
      const scriptHandle = await page.$('script[src*="googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=xxxxxxx' + gtmContainerId + '"]');
        if (!scriptHandle) {
        throw new Error('Não foi possível encontrar o script do GTM');
}
      const scriptSrc = await scriptHandle.evaluate(el => el.src);

      const gtmUrl = scriptSrc.split('id=xxxxxxx')[1].split('&')[0];
    
      const url = `https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=${gtmUrl}`;
    
      const response = await fetch(url);
      const text = await response.text();
    
      const dataLayerRegex = /dataLayer\s*=\s*(.+?);/;
      const match = text.match(dataLayerRegex);
    
      if (!match) {
        console.error('Camada de dados não encontrada');
        return {};
      }
    
      return JSON.parse(match[1]);
    }
    const datalayer = await getGtmDataLayer(page);
     
    // Função para escrever os dados em um arquivo local JSON
     fs.writeFile('datalayer.json', JSON.stringify(datalayer, null, 2), (err) => {
      if (err) throw new Error('Algo deu errado ao escrever o arquivo');

      console.log('Arquivo gravado com sucesso!');
    });

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }

})();
```

I believe that the failure is in the connection with the GTM to access the datalayer. Does anyone already made this kind of connection and can help me?

Comment: you don't need GTM if you're validating the DL. DL is a means of communication between FE and GTM, GTM is only meant to consume DL, not modify it and even if it did modify it, your tests shouldn't test GTM since any modification in GTM should be manually tested by Analytics.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response my friend. Can you help me by showing me a way with my code?

Comment: The code makes so little sense that I don't even know what to help with here. Just start over.

Comment: I will do the following : 
1. Load the page and wait until window load. 2. Check the datalayer by access `window.dataLayer`. 3. Run a loop maybe, to check the datalayer array contains anything you want.
But here is a question. Does the datalayer event you want to check will appear when window load?